# Can dumping and restoring database make it slower?

Tags: performance, postgresql, amazon-rds

I have a Amazon RDS Postgres database. I created a snapshot of this database(say database-A) and then restored the snapshot on a new db instance(say database-B). database-A was a 8 GiB machine with 2 cores. database-B is a 3.75 GiB machine with 1 core.

I find the following:

1. Storage occupied by database-B is greater than database-A. I found the occupied storage using pg_database_size.
2. I find the queries slower on database-B than they were on database-A.

Are these two things possible in normal scenario or I must have made some mistake during dump/restore process?

Comment: One core can make a difference. Anyway, can you compare plans?

Comment: @user_0 What about the increase in storage space?

Comment: Why? Before spending money I really suggest you to compare EXPLAIN ANALIZE of the query on both server if possible.

Comment: Did you run `analyze` after the import?

Comment: How much is the difference in size? Could you post the parameters of the pg_dump and pg_restore used?